# How can i rename a helm chart once created?

Tags: charts, kubernetes, dependencies, rename, kubernetes-helm

I have created a helm chart named "abc" with the command
`helm create abc`
Now when I install this chart, all the kuberenets resources created will have a name containing "abc".

Now I have to rename the chart "abc" to "xyz". 
If i use 
`helm install --name xyz ./abc`
only the chart name is changed to xyz. The resources inside it remain with "abc".

I need to rename the entire chart (with its resources) to be renamed.
Do I have any option for it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can access `xyz` with `{{ .Release.Name }}` and need to update the resource names with `{{ .Release.Name }}` so that the names are picked up dynamically every time:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ .Values.app.dbName }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ .Values.app.dbName }}
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ .Values.app.dbName }}
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: mysql:5.6
          name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-mysql" // or just {{ .Release.Name }}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this during the `helm create` command, so `{{ .Release.name }}` will already be in the templates?

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem many times and I found the simplest solution.
Just 2 steps:

1. find and replace the name in the chart files.
2. rename chart directory name

Very simple if your chart name is quite unique.

By default chart name is used in the files:
**Chart.yaml** and
**templates/_helpers.tpl**

Answer (score 0):

The approach mentioned here seems much better: https://engineering.salesforce.com/how-to-rename-a-helm-release-6fdcd7526ac7/

To summarize, you end up orphaning the resources and then re-adopting them IIUC. Note the markdown is a bit janky and amusingly the post actually references this question.

Would be nice if the helm folks just published a best practice here: https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/